# how to run asp.net website from iis7.5 and in windows7

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, iis-7.5

I am trying to run my website from iis7.5 and i am using windows7 OS.

after browsing the website, it gives error like this...

This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

how can i resolve this... please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` -> `<configSections>` -> `<sectionGroup name="system.webServer">`:

Change the attributes `<... overrideModeDefault="Deny" ...>` to `Allow` where needed (handlers, modules, ...).

or use the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) that will do it for you.

There are some command line tools for that as well I think.